# SharePoint Online provided hosted ribbon app running twice

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, client-object-model, csom, azure

I have a SharePoint Online provided hosted ribbon app (in Azure), the app perform query the document properties and check out the document, the problem is when the document process for 50 documents or more (approximately few minutes), the app running twice and perform the activities twice.

Question, is this the limitation of provided hosted app when it come to long running app? or the context expired and auto generate another? anyone has experience this before? please share the solution or suggestion.

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: What's triggering the method that is being called twice? Do you have a Remote Event Receiver implemented?

Comment: yes, I have item added and item updated RER implemented. If I remove the logic of check out 50 documents, then it is OK and not running twice.